# nginx times out on start

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I've installed `nginx` using this `sources.list.d` entry:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
```

The nginx version is `1.12.2-1~xenial`. The server is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with kernel `4.4.0-36-generic`.

My problem is that the `nginx` daemon fails to start:

```
$ sudo systemctl start nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Unfortunately, these logs don't provide much information:

```
$ sudo journalctl -xe
Feb 05 10:43:50 SERVERNAME nginx[17035]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Feb 05 10:43:50 SERVERNAME nginx[17035]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Feb 05 10:45:21 SERVERNAME systemd[1]: nginx.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 05 10:45:21 SERVERNAME systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Feb 05 10:45:21 SERVERNAME systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 05 10:45:21 SERVERNAME systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

From what I can tell, *nginx does indeed start correctly*. It's as if the parent process doesn't receive the "I am started" message from it's child process(es) correctly being the problem. When it's running (systemd waiting for it to start), I can successfully curl it like this:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.12.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel lost on this, apart from perhaps testing another `nginx` version or something. Any ideas? I could reboot the server but it feels silly on a Linux server.

*Update 9:56 UTC: Tested with `1.13.8-1~xenial`, same problem.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found the problem, this was a silly one...

I had started out my `nginx` configuration by copying the settings from a Docker container, which had this setting in its `nginx` configuration:

```
daemon off;
```

This was right in the Docker scenario (where the `nginx` process was running with `runit`, i.e. no `systemd`-style init was controlling it.) It had the effect that `nginx` would never daemonize, and return control to systemd -> it would be treated as "timed out with unknown problem", and `systemd` would kill it.

So, this ended up being a simple configuration error. I wanted to post it here, since it might help others who also make this clumsy mistake. :-)

Full details about this keyword: http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#daemon

Answer (score 0):

What might also be problematic is custom setting of pid localization in nginx.conf:

pid        ../logs/nginx.pid;

it must be alligned with the PIDFile setting in nginx.service file (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service):
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid

Here it is not ;]

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when copying the nginx configuration over to openresty. I had this line in the config and openresty would not start as a service:

```
pid /run/nginx.pid;
```